# Check if distribution per week is the same

Tags: statistics, distribution, hypothesis-testing

I have sales by customer (b2b) and by date. I want to check if the distribution per day inside weeks remains the same from week to week.

Initial dataset

| Customer | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 2019-02-23 | 527 |
| Beta | 2019-02-23 | 642 |
| Alpha | 2019-02-24 | 776 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Beta | 2021-07-28 | 1236 |

I transformed it into

| Customer | Week | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alpha | 201906 | 0.2202 | 0.15799 | 0.178202 | 0.160449 | 0.1528 | 0.130214 | 0.000067 |
| Beta | 201906 | 0.20573 | 0.183979 | 0.182207 | 0.179824 | 0.140596 | 0.107601 | 0.000061 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Beta | 202130 | 0.219794 | 0.181995 | 0.172113 | 0.156676 | 0.151771 | 0.117579 | 0.000072 |

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: have a look at ANOVA tests. i think they allow for comparing multiple categories. you can also just plot them on the same chart using the human brain for unsupervised learning!

Comment: Hi, problem related to statistics should be asked on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for more/better clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can create n matrices where n is the number of different products `{Alpha, Beta, ...,}` then for each different product you group your daily value into weekly so you have something like `Product1 :` `{week_1_sales,...,week_M_sales}` with those values you create a confusion squared matrix of dimension `MxM` with rows and columns `week_i_sales` and values are the [KS statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) (pairwise) so you can see if the distribution of the weekly sales for product changes from one week to another.

You would end with n different matrices with this information. Each individual matrix should look similar to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/KOLMOGOROV-SMIRNOV-K-S-DISSIMILARITY-MATRIX_tbl2_292944080) (just and example in your case rows and columns would be the week id):

[image]

Comment: What I am interested in is to check if the **daily distribution** (Monday to Sunday) remains the same for all weeks.